# perf_event_open - how to monitoring multiple events

Tags: c, linux, intel, perf

does anyone know how to set `perf_event_attr` struct that can trigger PMU to monitoring multiple (type) event via `perf_event_open()`?

Like `perf record -e cycles,faults ls`, it has two different event type (PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE and PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE), but in example on [perf_event_open's manpage](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), `perf_event_attr.type` can only assigned single value.

Any suggestion will be appreciate, thanks!

**20170208 Update**
Thanks for @gudok pointing me a direction, but the result seems some abnormal.
Demo program as below (for measure whole system's CPU cycle and cache miss):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;
  struct {
    uint64_t value;
    uint64_t id;
  } values[];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct perf_event_attr pea;
  int fd1, fd2;
  uint64_t id1, id2;
  uint64_t val1, val2;
  char buf[4096];
  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buf;
  int i,j;
  struct timespec time, time2;

  time.tv_sec = 1;
  time.tv_nsec = 0;

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd1 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.precise_ip = 2;  // want to using PEBS 
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, fd1 /*!!!*/, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);

  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  while (1) {
    nanosleep(&time, &time2);

    //ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);

    read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
    for (i = 0; i < rf->nr; i++) {
      if (rf->values[i].id == id1) {
        val1 = rf->values[i].value;
      } else if (rf->values[i].id == id2) {
        val2 = rf->values[i].value;
      }
    }

    printf("cpu cycles: %"PRIu64"\n", val1);
    printf("cache misses: %"PRIu64"\n", val2);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
cpu cycles: 120   // Just have about 120 CPU cycles in a second
cache misses: 0   // and doesn't have any cache miss?
cpu cycles: 233
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 352
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 455
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 562
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 673
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 794
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 907
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 1011
cache misses: 0
cpu cycles: 1129
cache misses: 3
cpu cycles: 1269
cache misses: 4
cpu cycles: 1423
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's a bit tricky.

We create first counter as usual. Additionally, we pass `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP` and `PERF_FORMAT_ID` to be able to work with multiple counters simultaneously. This counter will be our group leader.

```
struct perf_event_attr pea;
int fd1, fd2;
uint64_t id1, id2; 

memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
pea.disabled = 1;
pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
pea.exclude_hv = 1;
pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
fd1 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, -1, 0);
```

Next, we retrieve identifier for the first counter:

```
ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);
```

Second (and all further counters) are created in the same fashion with only one exception: we pass `fd1` value as group leader argument:

```
memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
pea.type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
pea.config = PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS;
pea.disabled = 1;
pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
pea.exclude_hv = 1;
pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, fd1, 0); // <-- here
ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);
```

Next we need to declare a data structure to read multiple counters at once. You have to declare different set of fields depending on what flags you pass to `perf_event_open`. Manual page mentions all possible fields. In our case, we passed `PERF_FORMAT_ID` flag which adds `id` field. This will allow us to distinguish between different counters.

```
struct read_format {
    uint64_t nr;
    struct {
        uint64_t value;
        uint64_t id;
    } values[/*2*/];
};
```

Now we call standard profiling ioctls:

```
ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
do_something();
ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
```

Finally, we read the counters from group leader file descriptor. Both counters are returned in single `read_format` structure that we declared:

```
char buf[4096];
struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buf;
uint64_t val1, val2;

read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
for (i = 0; i < rf->nr; i++) {
  if (rf->values[i].id == id1) {
    val1 = rf->values[i].value;
  } else if (rf->values[i].id == id2) {
    val2 = rf->values[i].value;
  }
}
printf("cpu cycles: %"PRIu64"\n", val1);
printf("page faults: %"PRIu64"\n", val2);
```

---

Below is the full program listing:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;
  struct {
    uint64_t value;
    uint64_t id;
  } values[];
};

void do_something() {
  int i;
  char* ptr;

  ptr = malloc(100*1024*1024);
  for (i = 0; i < 100*1024*1024; i++) {
    ptr[i] = (char) (i & 0xff); // pagefault
  }
  free(ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct perf_event_attr pea;
  int fd1, fd2;
  uint64_t id1, id2;
  uint64_t val1, val2;
  char buf[4096];
  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buf;
  int i;

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd1 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, fd1 /*!!!*/, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);


  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  do_something();
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);


  read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
  for (i = 0; i < rf->nr; i++) {
    if (rf->values[i].id == id1) {
      val1 = rf->values[i].value;
    } else if (rf->values[i].id == id2) {
      val2 = rf->values[i].value;
    }
  }

  printf("cpu cycles: %"PRIu64"\n", val1);
  printf("page faults: %"PRIu64"\n", val2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer :)
It works, but the result seems a little unusual..

I want to count CPU cycles per second, and it shows about only 120 cycles. Is the method I used incorrect? (Demo program updated in my question)

Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinChi, cpu cycles won't be counted during sleep calls. CPU time during sleep doesn't belong to current process. Inside `do_something`, you need to create a dummy loop of 1-2 bln. iterations and count 1) cpu cycles 2) time it took to perform this loop (`clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID)`). Dividing these two values will get you cpu cycles per second. Alternatively, you may setup a one second timer and run infinite loop until it fires.

Comment: @gudok, is there any limit on the number of elements that we can put into a group?

Comment: whenever I try to put more than 3 elements of type PERF_HW_CACHE in a group, it is giving garbage output.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh, check for `__NR_perf_event_open` errors. The combination of id, op_id, op_result_id that you are trying to use may be not available.

Comment: Where is PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP actually documented? I was having trouble because I didn't realize this flag is required to enable/reset/disable a group in the ioctl call. It's just sort of implied, but in the docs, but not explicitly stated. Is this a documentation bug?