# How to read from the file descriptor returned by __NR_perf_event_open

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, microbenchmark

I am reading the [code](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2023/03/21/performancecounters/linux-perf-events.h) written by Lemire which makes a benchmark of number of CPU cycles and instructions.

The following is the main logic:

```c
  #define N_CONFIG 2
  int CONFIGS[N_CONFIG] = {PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES, PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS};

  const int pid = 0;  // current process
  const int cpu = -1; // all cpus
  const unsigned long flags = 0;

  int group = -1; // no group
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_CONFIG; i++) {
    attr.config = CONFIGS[i];
    fd =
        (int)syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &event.attr, pid, cpu, group, flags);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &ids[i]);
    if (group == -1) {
      group = fd;
    }
 }
```

Then how to read the number of CPU cycles and instructions from `fd`?

In `end()` method:

```c
if (read(fd, temp_result_vec.data(), temp_result_vec.size() * 8) == -1) {
   report_error("read");
}
// our actual results are in slots 1,3,5, ... of this structure
```

How to understand "our actual results are in slots 1,3,5, ... of this structure"? This structure refers to `std::vector<uint64_t>` whose size is `2 * N_CONFIG + 1`.

---

[perf_event_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) provides an example to obtain the number of instructions, and it is very easy to follow, in which only ONE config (i.e., `PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS`) is used:

```c
long long count;
read(fd, &count, sizeof(count));
```

But it seems that when it comes to multiple configs at the same time, code becomes weird.

Comment: There is an example that does exactly what you want in the manual page for `perf_event_open`: https://manned.org/perf_event_open.2 (look at the very bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks. I finally understand what it is going on for multiple monitor events.

Answer (score 3):

> How to understand "our actual results are in slots 1,3,5, ... of this structure"?

Because this program is used to record two events (i.e., `PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES`, `PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS`), they need to be **grouped**, and the read format is specified as:

```c
PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID
```

If `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP` is specified, then what returns from `read` is:

```c
 struct read_format {
       u64 nr;            /* The number of events */
       struct {
            u64 value;     /* The value of the event */
            u64 id;        /* if PERF_FORMAT_ID */
        } values[nr];
 };
```

Therefore, as for two events here, the first position (i.e., slot 0) is `nr`; the second position is a value (i.e., slot 1); the third position is an ID (i.e., slot 2); the forth position is a value (i.e., slot 3); the fifth position is an ID (i.e., slot 4). That's why **actual results are in slots 1 and 3**.

A related question can be found at [perf_event_open - how to monitoring multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088515/perf-event-open-how-to-monitoring-multiple-events).

---

BTW, there is a bug in the [code](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2023/03/21/performancecounters/linux-perf-events.h). It wrongly updates `fd` in each iteration at [line 46](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/87f24593d246c54cf065a34f2a7aa7ea650a8094/2023/03/21/performancecounters/linux-perf-events.h#L46). Instead, we should record the first `fd` (when `i == 0`) as the group leader, and later we must use such `fd` to read statistics.

Comment: The author has fixed that bug.