# perf_event_open() to sampling multiple events using mmap()

Tags: c

I would like to use perf_event_open() system call to sample multiple hardware events using mmap(), just like "perf record -e cycles,instructions xxx". I have find a [good example](https://github.com/aleixrocks/perf_event_open-example/blob/master/test.c) from github, as shown below. The code works perfectly where I can read "PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS" into the ring buffer. Now I want to sample additional coutner value, e.g., "PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES" simultaneously. I read the [official doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) about perf_event_open(), I still not sure how to implement the code. There are some related topics in stackoverflow about reading mulitple events, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088515/perf-event-open-how-to-monitoring-multiple-events), but it is based on read() option. There seems to be no example of using mmap(). Can anyone helps me on this problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE (4*1024)

#define UNCORE_IMC_TYPE 12
#define UNCORE_IMC_EVENT_READ 0x01
#define UNCORE_IMC_EVENT_WRITE 0x02

static long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                   group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

static print_perf_macros()
{
    printf("perf_event_attr->type:\n");
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE);
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE);
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT);
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE);
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_RAW: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_RAW);
    printf(" - PERF_TYPE_BREAKPOINT: %d\n", PERF_TYPE_BREAKPOINT);

    printf("perf_event_mmap-page->type:\n");
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_MMAP: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_MMAP);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_LOST: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_LOST);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_COMM: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_COMM);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_EXIT: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_EXIT);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_THROTTLE: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_THROTTLE);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_UNTHROTTLE: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_UNTHROTTLE);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_FORK: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_FORK);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_READ: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_READ);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE);
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_MMAP2: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_MMAP2);
#ifdef PERF_RECORD_AUX
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_AUX: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_AUX);
#endif
#ifdef PERF_RECORD_ITRACE_START
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_ITRACE_START: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_ITRACE_START);
#endif
#ifdef PERF_RECORD_LOST_SAMPLES
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_LOST_SAMPLES: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_LOST_SAMPLES);
#endif
#ifdef PERF_RECORD_SWITCH
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_SWITCH: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_SWITCH);
#endif
#ifdef PERF_RECORD_SWITCH_CPU_WIDE
    printf(" - PERF_RECORD_SWITCH_CPU_WIDE: %d\n", PERF_RECORD_SWITCH_CPU_WIDE);
#endif
    printf("\n");
}

void print_sampling_info(struct perf_event_mmap_page *samp_info)
{
    printf("perf_event_mmap-page (not complete):\n");
    printf("  - version: %u\n", samp_info->version);
    printf("  - compat version: %u\n", samp_info->compat_version);
    printf("  - index: %u\n", samp_info->index);
    printf("  - offset: %lld\n", samp_info->offset);
    printf("  - time enabled: %llu\n", samp_info->time_enabled);
    printf("  - time running: %llu\n", samp_info->time_running);
    printf("  - cap_usr_time: %d\n", samp_info->cap_user_time);
    printf("  - cap_usr_rdpmc: %d\n", samp_info->cap_user_rdpmc);
    printf("  - pmc_width: %x\n", samp_info->pmc_width);
    printf("  - data_head: %lld\n", samp_info->data_head);
    printf("  - data_tail: %lld\n", samp_info->data_tail);
    printf("\n");
}

void compute_stuff()
{
    const size_t buf_size = 1024*1024*1024;
    char * buf;
    int sum, i;

    buf = (char *)malloc(buf_size);
    if (!buf) {
        perror("Cannot mmap memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < buf_size; i++) {
        sum += buf[i];
    }

    // this is to avoid compiler optimizations
    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
}

void print_header(struct perf_event_header *header)
{
    printf("perf_event_header:\n");
    printf(" - type:%u\n", header->type);
    printf(" - misc:%x\n", header->misc);
    printf(" - size:%u\n", header->size);
}

void print_raw_data(struct perf_event_header *header)
{
    void *post_header;
    uint32_t raw_size;
    char * raw_data;
    int i;

    post_header = (char *)header + sizeof(struct perf_event_header);
    raw_size = *((uint32_t *)post_header);
    raw_data = (char *)(post_header+sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf (" - raw_size:%d\n", raw_size);
    printf (" - raw_data: ");
    for (i = 0; i < raw_size; i++) {
        printf("%u ", raw_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int perf_sampling_example()
{
    int fd;
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    struct perf_event_mmap_page *samp_info;
    struct perf_event_header *header;
    const size_t mmap_size = 2*PAGE_SIZE;
    void *buffer;
    char *iter, *samples_end;
    unsigned long nrecords = 0;
    void *post_header;
    pid_t pid;
    int cpu;
    uint64_t *value;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.size        = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.type        = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.config      = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
    pe.sample_freq = 4000;
    pe.disabled    = 1;
    pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_READ; // store the value of the counter
    pe.mmap        = 1;
    pe.freq        = 1;

    pid = 0;
    cpu = -1;
    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, pid, cpu, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx: %d: %s\n",
            pe.config, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    buffer = mmap(NULL, mmap_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Cannot memory map sampling buffer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    samp_info = (struct perf_event_mmap_page *)buffer;

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    compute_stuff();

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);

    print_sampling_info(samp_info);

    samples_end = buffer + PAGE_SIZE + samp_info->data_head;
    //TODO memory barrier rmb

    iter = ((char *)buffer + PAGE_SIZE);
    while (iter < samples_end) {
        header = (struct perf_event_header *)iter;
        post_header = (char *)header + sizeof(struct perf_event_header);

        print_header(header);
        value = (uint64_t *)post_header;
        printf("   {value: %"PRIu64"}\n", *value);

        iter += header->size;
        nrecords++;
    }

    printf("total number of records: %lu\n", nrecords);

    if (munmap(buffer, mmap_size)) {
        perror("Cannot unmmap sampling buffer\n");
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

int perf_counting_example()
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    int sum;
    long long count;
    struct perf_event_attr pe;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    //pe.type     = UNCORE_IMC_TYPE;
    //pe.config   = UNCORE_IMC_EVENT_READ;
    pe.type     = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.config   = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
    pe.size     = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.disabled = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, -1, 0, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx: %d: %s\n",
            pe.config, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    compute_stuff();

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("total instructions: %llu\n", count);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    print_perf_macros();

    printf("\n################\n");
    printf("sampling example\n");
    printf("################\n\n");
    perf_sampling_example();

    printf("\n################\n");
    printf("counting example\n");
    printf("################\n\n");
    perf_counting_example();
}
```

I have tried to google, chatgpt and many options but could not find an answer. I will expect a working example written in C